# Is there established notation for the (semi)group of affine transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Is there an established notation for the group of invertible affine transformations of a vector space $V$, that is, $V \rtimes \mathrm{GL}(V)$, and the semigroup of (not necessarily invertible) transformations $V \rtimes \mathrm{End}(V)$? It seems that the former is often denoted by $\mathrm{Aff}(V)$ of $\mathrm{AGL}(V)$, while the use of google has yet to deliver results for the latter.

There are several posibilities that come to mind and I want to avoid using notation that would cause confusion/inconvenience/annoyance. Apologies if the question is too opinion based; if so feel free to close.